# Get parameter on rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a "subsection" in a website. Something like "www.site.com/subsection".

In short, I generate a controller, and added  route:

```
get :id, to section#show
```

Everything load nicely, but the view is not able to get the parameter. Bellow, the code to send it to the view:

```
@parameter = params[':id']
```

Here go the code in print the parameter.

```
<%= @parameter %>
```

I used those same codes in other controller, that I created only for test. And that work nicely.

Any clue?

Is that something related to a root or anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: You want "www.site.com/subsection/subsection_id" or "www.site.com/subsection_id"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
# router.rb
get '/:id', to: "section#show"

# controller
@parameter = params[:id]
```

remove ''.

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it!